# Sort a Core Data set by attribute on a related entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a Core Data model with a WORKOUT entity, which has a to-many relationship with an EXERCISE entity.

I have a set of exercises for a particular user, but I'd like to sort these by their workoutDate, an attribute on the WORKOUT entity.

How do I perform a sort on my set against an attribute on a related object?

Ideally I'd like to do something like this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"workout.workoutDate" ascending:NO selector:@selector(compare:)];
return [self.exercises sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

Comment: You should be able to sort this when you create your fetched results controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sort descriptor looks fine at first sight.
But `self.exercises` is an `NSSet`. For sorting, you have to convert it to an `NSArray`
with `allObjects`:

```
[[self.exercises allObjects] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:…]
```

Alternatively, you can execute a fetch request on the "EXERCISE" entity, 
with a predicate that restricts the result to all exercises of the current user,
and your sort descriptor. (How this predicate looks exactly depends on your relationship
from "EXERCISE" to "USER".)